# Counts from two joined tables are showing the same even though they should not be

Tags: mysql

I have a pretty straight forward query that selects couple business name and counts results from other two joined tables. For some reason I get the same number of offers as rules, even though the number is only correct for rule.

For example I have 2 offers and 6 rules. Returned results show both as 6.

What am I missing?

```
SELECT
    business_profile.busID,
    business_profile.busName,
    COUNT(business_offers.ofr_id) AS cntOffers,
    COUNT(business_rules.rule_id) AS cntRules
FROM business_profile
LEFT JOIN business_offers ON (business_offers.ofr_busID = business_profile.busID)
LEFT JOIN business_rules ON (business_rules.rule_busID = business_profile.busID)
WHERE business_profile.busID > 1
GROUP BY business_profile.busID
ORDER BY cntRules DESC, cntOffers DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Try `COUNT (DISTINCT ...)`

Comment: Otherwise you're just counting the number of rows, the column name is irrelevant (except that null values are not counted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` so you don't count the same ID multiple times.

```
SELECT
    business_profile.busID,
    business_profile.busName,
    COUNT(DISTINCT business_offers.ofr_id) AS cntOffers,
    COUNT(DISTINCT business_rules.rule_id) AS cntRules
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks for such a prompt response.